# "Syntax error at or near FROM" after a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
INSERT INTO summary
    SELECT 
        rental_date,
        category_name,
        MAX(rcount) as rcount FROM (
            SELECT COUNT(rental_id) from detailed as rcount) as subquery
FROM detailed
GROUP BY genre, month
ORDER BY month DESC;
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 7:  FROM detailed
         ^
```

This is my first time using a subquery to nest aggregate functions, so I'm not very familiar with the syntax.

What am I missing?

Comment: Should be one FROM per SELECT.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A [mcve] would make things much clearer.

Comment: you don't need a subquery here, use a window function - it's not correlated anyway so you'll have the same value on every row

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1):

If you indent properly...

```
INSERT INTO summary
    SELECT 
        rental_date,
        category_name,
        MAX(rcount) as rcount
    FROM (
            SELECT COUNT(rental_id) from detailed as rcount
    ) as subquery
    FROM detailed  -- <----- Second FROM!!!
    GROUP BY genre, month
    ORDER BY month DESC
;
```

Perhaps you should rather explain your exact goal in order to us being able to help you...

**EDIT:** Maybe something like this...?

```
INSERT INTO summary
    SELECT 
        rental_date,
        category_name,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(rental_id) from detailed
        ) as rcount
    FROM detailed
    GROUP BY genre, month
    ORDER BY month DESC
;
```

...or just:

```
INSERT INTO summary
    SELECT 
        rental_date,
        category_name,
        count(rental_id) over () as rcount
            -- (Search for window functions in Postgres manual)
    FROM detailed
    GROUP BY genre, month
    ORDER BY month DESC
;
```